# How to redirect user if direct access image files by browser? [nginx]

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting

How do I redirect if a user tries to direct access image files in browser only? I want to still keep the ability to allow social media sites to embed our images by hotlinking. I just want only if a user direct access image by browser to redirect.

This is my nginx conf

```
proxy_cache_path /var/www/img.example.com/htdocs/cache-store levels=1:2 keys_zone=pixstore:10m max_size=5g inactive=7d use_temp_path=off;
server {

    server_name img.example.com www.img.example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/img.example.com.access.log ;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/img.example.com.error.log;

    add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    location / {
        proxy_cache pixstore;
        proxy_cache_revalidate on;
        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_cache_lock on;
        add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
        proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8090;
        proxy_redirect off;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 7d;
        proxy_cache_valid 404 5m;
    }

    location ~ "^/c/600x1200_90_webp/img-master/img/\d+/\d+/\d+/\d+/\d+/\d+/((?<filenum>\d+)[^/]+\.(jpg|png|webp))$" {
    valid_referers server_names;
    proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8090;
    if ($invalid_referer = "0") {
    return 301 http://view.example.com/artwork/$filenum; }
    }

}
```

The redirect isn't working. How can I fix this?

Comment: To match your example URI, you should add one more `\d+/`. Complete location can be `location ~ "^/c/600x1200_90_webp/img-master/img/\d+/\d+/\d+/\d+/\d+/\d+/((?<filenum>\d+)[^/]+\.(jpg|png|webp))$" { return 301 https://example.com/detail?id=$filennum; }`

Comment: The more important question to me: What are the difference between a Useres request from a webbrowser and a requsest comming from a social media platform? What are the differences between those two? UserAgent? Refferer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider referer. [Here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html) is nginx module, and [here](https://havecamerawilltravel.com/allowed-referrers-sharing-social-media-shared-link-images-when-using-hotlink-protection/) is an article with some explanation, and [gist](https://gist.github.com/Ephigenia/1295164) with piece of code. So basically - you need to have the module and then you can use something like this:

```
# apply this rule on any location that’s an image using Regexp
location ~* \.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|swf|ico)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
    # block empty blocked or whiteliste referers
    valid_referers none blocked ~\.example.com ~\.google\. ~\.yahoo\. ~\.bing\. ~\.facebook\. ~\.fbcdn\.;
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

Where `example.com` is your domain. Let me know how it goes - I'll update answer if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be a lot better off doing it with something like Node.js and testing the User Agent string against a regular expression and if it contains something that browsers have like the text "Chrome" "Firefox" etc in it then redirect.

Answer (score 0):

How about whitelisting social media's agent IP instead?

For example, this is how you find all IP address used by [Facebook's agent](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler/)

```
whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | grep ^route
```

then add this to your nginx conf

```
location ~ /(?<filenum>\d+)[^/]*\.(jpg|png|webp)$ {
    allow 69.63.176.0/20;
    allow 66.220.144.0/20;
    ...
    deny all;
    error_page 403 http://view.example.com/artwork/$filenum;
}
```

And perhaps, you may want to check you regex using [this site](https://nginx.viraptor.info/)